# How to pronunce "acheter" - Is it "Ach-te" or "Ach-e-te"?

Tags: prononciation

I'm learning french and I have notice that lot's of people say "Ach-te" instead of "Ach-e-te" when it comes to the verb "Acheter".

Try to write`Que puis-je acheter` and listen.
https://ttsmp3.com/

But google translate says "Ach-te". One french teacher at Udemy from the courses "3 Minutes French" says "Ach-te"

So what is correct? Is it dialect?

Comment: I guess this happens with many languages: in casual (and faster) speech: not all syllabs are always articulated. The correct, or let's say best articulated way, is "Ach-e-té".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*E caduc*/schwa realization is a regional and individual choice.

In careful speech and poetry this *E* is generally pronounced. It is also the case by people with the southern French accent.

In all other contexts, it is most often skipped.

Comment: Ok. So "ach-te" is more common by these dialects of france? Is there any special with southern france when it comes to dialect?

Comment: The other way round People having a southern French accent (*accent du midi*) would more likely pronounce three syllables "a-che-té" instead of two syllables "ach-tè" pronounced elsewhere. These variants are not really referred to as dialects but just as French spoken with various accent.